# Populate Dropdown list with CSV file - d3

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I want to populate simple drop down list in html , 
with values that exist in csv file.
I try something like that , but it doesn't work.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
d3.csv("valuesforDD.csv", function(error, data) {

 var select = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .append("select")


      select.selectAll("option")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("option")
        .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
        .text(function (d) { return d; });

        }

</script>

</html>
```

What should I change?

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) uses the first line of the CSV file as the column names.  You should make sure your CSV file looks something like the following:

   ```
   value,label
   1,"Item 1"
   2,"Item 2"
   3,"Item 3"
   ```
2. You must use a field name when accessing the data in the `attr` and `text` functions.  Using the above CSV file, you would use `d.value` and `d.label`.

Here is an updated version of your code that you should be able to use and adapt as needed:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script>
  d3.csv("valuesforDD.csv", function(error, data) {
    var select = d3.select("body")
      .append("div")
      .append("select")

    select
      .on("change", function(d) {
        var value = d3.select(this).property("value");
        alert(value);
      });

    select.selectAll("option")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            // just declare the d3 js path and put the following code in script tag,
            // change the 'billedTo_list' to your p tag as in below code of HTML.

        <!-- HTML code for select box to populate start here -->
        <table class="seller-desc reciever-desc">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <address>
                        <p class="billedTo_list">Billed To</p>
                    </address>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
<span class="to-addres"><input id="name" class="billed_firm" type="text" contenteditable value="M/S."></span>
<span class="to-addres"><input id="name" class="billed_address1" type="text" contenteditable value="Address : "></span><br>
<span class="to-addres"><input id="name" class="billed_address2" type="text" contenteditable value=""></span><br>
<span class="to-addres"><input id="name" class="billed_phno" type="text" contenteditable value="Ph. No. : "></span><br>
<span class="to-addres"><input id="name" class="billed_gstin" type="text" contenteditable value="GSTIN No. :  "></span><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- HTML code for select box to populate ends here -->

        <!-- javascript code for select box to populate start here -->

            // select the place where you want to add your select box
            var body = d3.select("p.billedTo_list");

            // add the select box dynamically to the div or any element of html
            var menu = body.append("select");

            // pass the csv file name here, it may cause error for direct accessing file install the plugin for chrome for external url access
            d3.csv("example.csv", function(d) {
                return {
                    rank : d.rank,
                    place : d.place,
                    population : d.population,
                    lat : d.lat,
                    lon : d.lon
                };
            }, function(data) {
                menu.selectAll("foo")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("option")
                .attr("value", d=>d.place)
                .text(d=>d.place);

                // on change select box it will show the related values 
                menu.on("change", function() {
                    var selected_value = $('.billedTo_list select').val();                      
                    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                        if(value.place == selected_value) {
                            $('.billed_name').val('M/S. ' + value.place);
                            $('.billed_address').val('Address : ' + value.population);
                            $('.billed_phno').val('Ph. No. : ' + value.lat);
                            $('.billed_gstin').val('GSTIN No. : ' + value.lon);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        <!-- javascript code for select box to populate start here -->
```

Comment: Please add description to answer. @Harshal

Comment: check the code now ... its so simple to understand ... html code at top and below the js code thats it...