# Getting values from combobox to d3 function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 code, i am trying to get the value from combobox and update my bubbles according to that value.

My code is here:

```
function updateData(value) {

    d3.csv("markalar.csv", function(err, capitalso) {

        capitalso.forEach(function(i){

            console.log(value.selectedIndex)

            var newSelect = document.createElement('select');
            newSelect.id = 'newselect';  

            addpoint(i.CapitalLongitude, i.CapitalLatitude, i.Sehir, i.key(function (d) {
                return 'newselect';
            }));
        });
    });  

};
```

I am trying to update values by clicking combobox.
This part of the code:

```
 addpoint(i.CapitalLongitude, i.CapitalLatitude, i.Sehir, i.key(function (d) return 'newselect';}));
```

normally works like this:

```
 addpoint(i.CapitalLongitude, i.CapitalLatitude, i.Sehir, i.Zara);
```

Comment: Can you please show what the addpoint() function looks like?

Comment: function addpoint(lat,lon,text,num) {
  var gpoint = g.append("g");//.attr("class", "gpoint");
  
   var x = projection([lat,lon])[0];
  var y = projection([lat,lon])[1];
  var radius = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .domain([0, 40])
    .range([0, 10]);
var color = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 40])
  .range(["#8B0773", "#8B0773"]);
  gpoint.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y)
         .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(num);})
  .attr("opacity",0.7)
        .attr("r", function(d) { return radius(num*3); })

Comment: @SeemantKulleen function is at the comment above.

Comment: Thank you, @PatriciaPoliws.  Next quetion: how are you populating the combo box? Are you setting it statically or dynamically (looks like you have some code that's trying to do that above?)

Comment: @SeemantKulleen my combobox code is like this:

Comment: function updateData(value) {
                  d3.csv("markalar.csv", function(err, capitalso) {
                     capitalso.forEach(function(i){
                       /* console.log(value.selectedIndex)
            var newSelect = document.createElement('select');
         newSelect.id = 'newselect';*/
   

                        addpoint(i.CapitalLongitude, i.CapitalLatitude, i.Sehir, i.Zara);

Comment: Unfortunately its not dynamic. I tried but couldnt make it. addpoint(i.CapitalLongitude, i.CapitalLatitude, i.Sehir, i.Zara); this part works statically but i have to convert is to dynamic.

Comment: Check here for how to populate a combo box dynamically from d3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24589035/1968883